# TeeChart data import from Excel

Tags: excel, import, teechart

I am evaluating TeeChart improved chart option managing data with excel but it is impossible/not clear/poor explained on TeeChart tutorial how to import X, Y and Z data (i.e. 3D scatterplot) from excel datasheet. No reason to buy a very good sw if too problematic to import data. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To be able to provide an accurate reply we'd need to know the TeeChart version you are using: VCL, ActiveX, .NET, Java, PHP, etc. Thanks in advance.